# (Android) Draw a line on the map using a .geojson file

Tags: java, json, mapbox, geojson

I am working on a bus application and I need to show a route that is used. With that, I used the MapBox website, drew a route using the data set and the logo after I exported a route in .geojson format, I would like to know if I can draw a line on my map on android from this file, instead of placing a point to point in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a `LineString` can be drawn with a Mapbox Maps SDK `LineLayer`.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/search?q=LineLayer&unscoped_q=LineLayer

You might find these Mapbox demo app examples especially helpful and inspirational:

- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/draw-a-geojson-line/
- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/create-a-line-layer/
- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/moving-icon-with-trailing-line/
- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/snaking-directions-route/
- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/marker-following-route/

The Annotation Plugin is another option for drawing lines https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/. You can use a local file with the Plugin, as seen at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/LineActivity.java#L89